# Profile creation

Tags: python, validation, form, django

I was creating a view with Django that would create a user profile for a website and this is what I came up with:

```
if (request.POST):
    required = set( ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 
        'address_1', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code'] )
    if (not (required <= set(request.POST))):
        return render( request, 'profiles/create.html', { 'missing' : required - set(request.POST) } )
    username = request.POST['username']
    email = request.POST['email']
    if (not Profile.is_unique(email)):
        return render( request, 'profiles/create.html', {'message' : 'Email address already exists!'} )
    first_name = request.POST['first_name']
    last_name = request.POST['last_name']
    password = request.POST['password']
    address_1 = request.POST['address_1']
    address_2 = request.POST['address_2'] if 'address_2' in request.POST else None
    city = request.POST['city']
    state = request.POST['state']
    zip_code = request.POST['zip_code']
    new_id = Create(username, email, first_name, last_name, password, address_1,
        city, state, zip_code, address_2)
    return redirect('profiles.views.Details', profile_id = new_id)
else:
    return render(request, 'profiles/create.html')
```

I am about 65% happy with this code as it is, especially the use of sets. However, there are some areas I would like to improve on:

1. Is there any way I could avoid assigning to individual variables from the `request.POST` calls, maybe using `setattr`? Would that be faster or slower than doing it this way?
2. I have a large `if` at the top which checks whether or not the page has been submitted already to avoid error messages popping up the first time somebody navigates to the page but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
required = set( ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 
    'address_1', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code'] )
```

You can just use `{}`:

```
required = {'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 
    'address_1', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code'}
```

You don't need a lot of parenthesis around your `if` statements, so:

```
if (request.POST):
```

becomes:

```
if request.POST:
```

In the `if` statement:

```
if (not (required <= set(request.POST))):
```

You can first get rid of the outer parenthesis:

```
if not (required <= set(request.POST)):
```

<strike>Instead of saying `not <=` you can just do `<`:</strike>

```
if set(request.POST) < required:
```

as it reads:

> You have less than you need for the required fields.

I would not make so many trivial variables such as:

```
username = request.POST['username']
```

Just use `request.POST['username']`. You don't use `username`, `email` ... that often, I would just use `request.POST['thing']` to save space. Although there are many reasons not to make code as terse as possible, adding lots of these variable declarations makes your code hard to read.

Comment: Your first and last points especially were helpful. However, I have to disagree with you on your `if set(request.POST) < required:` statement. `request.POST` may contain items which are not in `required` but I want to check whether or not everything in `required` is also in `request.POST`, i.e. whether or not `required` is a subset of `request.POST`. An example of something in `request.POST` but not in `required` would be the `address_2` field, which is not required.